# how to plot a part of map but with limitation arround it

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, gis

how to plot something like this:

see image here, I didn't have 10 reputation so I can not post image, so paste a image URL here.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/97751721@N07/9089566951
or
http://www.flickr.com/photos/97751721@N07/9091786734

right part of this map is a zoom in map with limitation, that is what I want

if it is use R code or other program language will be more great!

Answer (score 1):

If your have everything as Spatial object you could simply plot with standard plot() and set lim to what ever you like.

```
require(maptools)

shape <- readShapePoints("shapefile.shp")

plot(shape, xlim=c(minXcoordinate, maxXcoordinate) ylim=c(minYcoordinate, maxYcoordinate))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear to me what exactly you want to do. Do you just want to make a map with a specific set of lon/lat boundaries? Do you need to plot data on top of it? Do you need to control the appearance to make it look like the example you give (with line boundaries & minimal geographic information)?

The `ggmap` package may get you started on this. The syntax goes like this:

```
require(ggmap)
# The location argument defines the center of the map
exampleMap <- get_map(location = c(lon = -95, lat = 30), zoom=5)
ggmap(exampleMap)
```

You can then add data to the map if you like (exactly how is left as an exercise to the motivated student!)

Comment: You are so quickly to answer the question, thank you, let me have a try.

Comment: sorry for my poor English. I am not a English speaker.can it plot my own data, not use google map data? and the limitation units can it with degree symbol? I want my map plot more or less like what I upload to http://www.flickr.com/photos/97751721@N07/9089566951

Comment: `ggmap` can only make maps based on Google maps or similar online sources (Open Street Maps, etc). What format is the data you are trying to map? You will use different approaches depending on how your data is encoded.

Comment: raster format, can convert to other format, it's easy to plot without degree symbol based limitation, but if I want the limitation with well looked degree symbol that's the hard.

Comment: It will help if you post a minimal, reproducible example, including a downloadable example of your raster file. Also, please make clear in your question that your problem is how to add axis labels with degree symbols.

Comment: In fact, I think I want a partial enlarged view, but if can not do that, then a map with latitude and longitude coordinates is also OK, so I can synthesize a partial enlarged view using photoshop